# Faster way to Unzip jsons files with python

Tags: python, json

I have a program that downloads directories and then unzip these directories and finally decompress all json's files inside each directory.
I have to download 1260 directories and each directory has 1000 files with 300 MB.
So looks like this:

```
di1.zip
  |_file1.json.gz
  ...
  |_file1000.json.gz
di2.zip
  |_file1.json.gz
  ...
  |_file1000.json.gz
....
dir1260.zip
  |_file1.json.gz
  ...
  |_file1000.json.gz
```

This is my code:

```
def ProcesssDir(dirs_links_file):

with open(dirs_links_file, 'r') as inputFile:
    lines = inputFile.readlines()
    for line in lines:

        #Download
        directory = subprocess.Popen("wget -c " + line, shell=True).wait() 

        #Unzip:
        for nameDirZip in glob.glob('*.zip'):
            UnzipDir = zipfile.ZipFile(nameDirZip)
            UnzipDir.extractall()
            nameDir = nameDirZip[:-4] + "/" #This is just to get the name of the new dir.

            subprocess.Popen("gunzip -d " + nameDir + "*.gz", shell=True).wait()
```

This works but very very ..very slow. Took like 20 min for each directory.
How can i do this faster?

Comment: That is 1.2 seconds per file.  How fast did you expect it to be?